# Difference between sort of agree and half agree

Tags: word-usage, difference

I would like to know if there is any difference between "I half agree " and "I sort of agree".

I have searched Internet and find the meaning of "sort of" meaning " to some extent "

So do both means the same?

Answer (score 2):

They *could* mean the same, but when someone says "I half agree" they likely mean, "There are some parts of what you said I agree with, and other parts I disagree with". On the other hand, "I sort of agree" usually means something similar to, "I don't disagree, but I'm not convinced yet", or "I agree with what I understood, but I didn't understand everything", or "I mostly disagree, but I'm being polite".